# Code to enable/disable internet connectivity

Tags: c#, internet-connection

I need to write some code to trigger internet connectivity on a computer. By default,internet should not work.

But,after installing my program,internet should work.

Ofcourse the computers are connected to my server and normally access internet through DHCP right now. But,give me some ideas to make things in such a way that only installing my program enables internet connectivity.

Thanks

Comment: Are you attempting a denial of service on a users computer? Technically you can't stop a user from using the Internet, think about it, they could just re-start in safe mode with networking and whatever program you have to "stop" the internet wouldn't even load.  This seems like a bad practice anyway to try to prevent people from using a resource.

Comment: No I don't want to stop the internet.

I wish i could make some server program to be installed on the server

and client program to be installed on the client.

I want to enable internet when client authenticates with server...
Thats my idea...but I have no idea how to go ahead...

Comment: So you want to force a person to authenticate with your server before they can use the internet?

Comment: @jagd - Yes..Exactly....but automatically authenticate in some manner

Comment: Josh, when you say server, do you mean an internet server or your wireless router? Are you trying to block people from borrowing/stealing wireless internet access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you don't want to use one, but the correct & easiest tool to use would be a proxy.

You'd have to program something to enable some client/server/proxy communication, but a proxy would be the way to go.

But maybe we're not understanding your requirements- why is a proxy out of the question?

I'm curious to know if a vpn setup would work for you. Although that's just a variation on a proxy..

edit:
Check out Squid - I don't know what you're using for the rest of your environment, but it supports [mysql authentication](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Authenticate/Mysql).  There is an 'enable' flag on the mysql table that you could control with your server.

Good luck!

Comment: yeah,something like a vpn setup is a great idea!!!

I don't mind using some specialized authentication program like a proxy...but not a normal socks/http proxy configuration on browsers

Comment: But How do I implement a VPN setup programmatically?

Comment: That was a great idea...I really appreciate it...i never thought of that so long. But then I need a way to programmatically do VPN connection during logon invisibly.

Comment: I think if a VPN is OK, then a proxy would be better- without the overhead of the secure tunnel it does the same thing!

Answer (score 0):

Zone Alarm does something similar, where I've seen it disable "interet access" i.e. certain ports when it thinks you have a trojan.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how you would disable internet access in the first place, before your program even exists on the computer.

However, if you are bound to a corporate network, maybe a group policy that forces Internet Explorer to use a specific proxy (your program in this case). That way, web browsing doesn't work until your program is loaded. And another group policy that disables the possibility to change proxy settings. To prevent these things in Chrome, Opera, Firefox etc. is another matter....

Comment: No,I don't want to use a proxy though.
I don't want to stop the internet.I'll disable internet on the server. I wish i could make some server program to be installed on the server and client program to be installed on the client. I want to enable internet when client authenticates with server... Thats my idea...but I have no idea how to go ahead...

Answer (score 0):

Ah, this is an easy one then. Buy a router, install it, go to 192.168.1.1, enter your password, then set it up to authenticate based on MAC addresses, or to require user passwords, whichever more closely resembles your current plan :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do falls in the realm of 802.1x.  Read up on that technology and the possibilities of enabling outbound routes once a user has authenticated.