# Can i write a program to limit the Internet usage to 40mb per day?

Tags: c#, .net, bandwidth

My Friend asked me to write a program to limit the Internet usage to 40 Mb per day. If the 40 Mb of daily quota is reached no other programs in the system must be able to access the Internet.

Comment: I don't know it exactly, but maybe some routers will provide such a functionality.

Comment: Does your friend intend to pay you? If not, why not? How about just purchasing a program, like [NetLimiter](http://netlimiter.com/)

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: he will not pay. I just want to program it. For him and for me also.

Comment: @Chris: Just a guess, but it seems like he just wants to learn.

Comment: Sounds like a fun little project.

Comment: @vishnu I think you're going to find that it's a lot of work, so my question was really: is it worth it?

Comment: if it is a hard project. i would like to try it

Comment: Write a proxy server.  Configure Control Panel + Internet to use that proxy.

Comment: @Hans Passant: will all other applications connect through that proxy server or will have to configure all applications one by one to use the proxy? is writing a proxy easy. pls help

Comment: Yes, they'll use the proxy automatically if they care about making an Internet connection.  It isn't hard with TcpListener.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. You need to monitor the network activity. One can use [IPGlobalProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.aspx) class for that.

   Keep in mind that the statistics are reseted each time the connection is lost so you'll have to store them somewhere.
2. You need to disable internet connection, see [Code to enable/disable internet connectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870006/code-to-enable-disable-internet-connectivity)

Answer (score 4):

Tell him you wrote a program, but instead hire a guy to watch his internet usage, and pull out the plug when the limit is hit.

EDIT: Apparently my sense of humor is off.

Anyway I think this would be quite an undertaking, I could not find any code for it. But I did find this [Net Limiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

More of a proof of concept than a working solution.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const double ShutdownValue = 40960000D;
            const string NetEnable = "interface set interface \u0022{0}\u0022 DISABLED";
            const string NetDisable = "interface set interface \u0022{0}\u0022 ENABLED";

            double Incoming = 0;
            double Outgoing = 0;
            double TotalInterface;
            string SelectedInterface = "Local Area Connection";

            NetworkInterface netInt = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().Single(n => n.Name.Equals(SelectedInterface));

            for (; ; )
            {
                IPv4InterfaceStatistics ip4Stat = netInt.GetIPv4Statistics();

                Incoming += (ip4Stat.BytesReceived - Incoming);
                Outgoing += (ip4Stat.BytesSent - Outgoing);
                TotalInterface = Incoming + Outgoing;

                string Shutdown = ((TotalInterface > ShutdownValue) ? "YES" : "NO");

                if (Shutdown == "YES")
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("netsh", string.Format(NetDisable, SelectedInterface));
                }

                string output = string.Format("Shutdown: {0} | {1} KB/s", Shutdown, TotalInterface.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(output);

                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i would just like to note, that there are errors in this snippet. i added them on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This should be doable in a router or with cFosSpeed which also provides quotas, however I do now know any freeware/open-source applications that already do this.

For writing it yourself you'd have to somehow keep count of the amount of data sent so far, and if multiple computers are on the same network it's going to be even harder to keep track of.